# Liouville-Roth Irrationality Measure of $\pi$ = 2 already proven?

Tags: transcendence-theory

I was looking through [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.08817.pdf)
and I was curious. Has it already been established that the Flint Hills series $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}\frac{\csc^2 n}{n^3}$ converges? And has it already been established that the Liouville-Roth irrationality measure of $\pi$ is equal to 2?

Comment: Do you really want the term $n=0$ in there?

Comment: Note that I wrote $n\in\mathbb{Z}^\mathbf{+}$

Comment: Flawed, too many mistakes to comment. The "proof" of Lemma 3.1 would imply an *explicit* upper bound on partial quotients of $\pi$ far below [known values](https://oeis.org/A033089). It remains to backtrack it.